# Python upscale image without blur PIL

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, antialiasing

[image]

I want to upscale an image using PIL. I have tried all of the antialiasing options, but none of them are right (I actually want no antialiasing at all). I don't want any blur, but a similar effect to texture packs in Minecraft.

This question has been asked before, but in Java:
[How to upscale an image without it becoming blurry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22183432/how-to-upscale-an-image-without-it-becoming-blurry)

The solution was `Bitmap#createScaledBitmap()`

Can somebody give me an equivalent function for Python (please standard library)?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you want no anitaliasing, just omit the last argument -- i.e. `d = c.size((1000, 700))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @martineau pointed out in a comment:

> If you want no anitaliasing, just omit the last argument -- i.e. `d = c.size((1000, 700))`.

Ommiting the last argument solved my problem.

Answer (score 7):

The selected answer does not work with the 2020 API. 
[`PIL.Image.BOX`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#concept-filters) is the right filter for upscale without blur, i.e.

```
from PIL import Image
c = Image.open(example)
d = c.resize((1000,700), resample=Image.BOX)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [nearest neighbour resampling filter](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize).

Comment: I have uploaded an image which is resized using the nearest neighbour filter , but the output is still blurry. Thanks anyway

Comment: @JuliusNaeumann: The value for Image.NEAREST == 0, not 1. You should the constant rather than hard-coding the value.